# Оставить ФИО из строки и передать в формулу

Tags: python-3.x

Строка:

```
Разработал:       студент                    СЖДт – 523 Анищенко С.С.
```

Желаемый результат:

```
^AАнищенко^BС. С.^G
```

Дело в том, что я пыталась убрать все пробелы replace, но в каждом файле их количество разное и приходится каждый раз пересчитывать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как оставить в строке только ФИО. Заранее благодарна за ответ

Comment: Избавиться от пробелов можно проще - [split](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: @de_frag, благодарю за комментарий. Про split я знаю. Но мне нужно оставить только ФИО

Comment: Берете последние два элемента массива (после операции split) и "склеиваете" их в ФИО. Или такое не подходит?

Comment: @de_frag, все сработало. Спасибо!!!